# Send schedule emails from sendgrid using c#

Tags: c#, email, azure, sendgrid, bulk

I am using [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/) for sending email in my application . Now i want to send emails to my users on weekly basis . Is there any feature available in sendgrid and if yes then how can i use that api in c#

Comment: Have you checked Sendgrid's website/documentation or contacted their support?

Comment: yes i think the call that marketing email , but still i don't know how to use that api in c#

Comment: For scheduling emails, just search for Azure Webjobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD:** Sendgrid does support scheduled emails as of v3 API. Please see [answer from P.Campbell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44877050/809357)

<strike>Sendgrid does not do scheduled emails.</strike>

You'll have to create schedule functionality yourself. I can recommend looking on [Azure Scheduler](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/) and [Scheduled Azure WebJobs](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/). Scheduled WebJobs are working in pair with Azure Scheduler and you can program them to do whatever you need (send emails) on  a regular basis (once a week).

Comment: I downvoted your (admittedly 3 year old answer) as it's incorrect. SendGrid has enabled scheduled sends for emails with the `SendAt` property in its v3 API. I realize that this answer was correct at the time.

Answer (score 13):

SendGrid supports scheduled sends of emails with one line of code extra.

Use the [`SendGridMessage.SendAt`](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/a8c8422e6e6df2b153d048703d411ea651fef77d/src/SendGrid/Helpers/Mail/SendGridMessage.cs#L97) property. It expects a UNIX timestamp as a `long`.

> Gets or sets a unix timestamp allowing you to specify when you want your email to be sent from SendGrid. This is not necessary if you want the email to be sent at the time of your API request.

```
int sendAtUnixTime = new DateTimeOffset(sendOnUtcDateTime).ToUnixTimeSeconds();

var client = new SendGridClient("apiKey");
var from = new EmailAddress("fromEmailAddress", "fromName");
var to = new EmailAddress("toEmailAddress", "toName");
var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, "subject", "", "bodyHtml");
msg.SendAt = sendAtUnixTime;                
var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
```

Comment: Take into consideration that you can only schedule up to 72 hours in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a worker role and defile time to run every week (simple logic). it can read your website database and send the emails to the users you want to mail.